# How to implement CustomStringConvertible on non-RawRepresentable enum conforming to protocol?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

Consider the following code, which consists of:

- A protocol, `P`
- Two enums, `E0` and `E1` that conform to `P`
- A function, `f(p:)` that takes an instance of `P` as an argument

```
import Foundation

protocol P { }

enum E0: P { case a }

enum E1: P { case b }

func f(p: P) {
    print("\(type(of: p)).\(p)")
}

let e0_a = E0.a
let e1_b = E1.b

f(p: e0_a)  // prints "E0.a"
f(p: e1_b)  // prints "E1.b"
```

I would like to be able to print a string that describes the `p` argument in the form:

"`Name of type implementing P`.`case of P`"

As shown in the function `f()`, this works just fine and I get the output I want.

What I would like to do, if possible, is implement a `CustomStringConvertible` extension on `P` that generates the same string.

Is this possible?

Here's one approach that doesn't work:

```
protocol P: CustomStringConvertible { }

extension P {
    var description: String { return "\(type(of: self).\(self)" }
}
```

This doesn't work because `\(self)` causes `description` to recursively call itself until the stack overflows.

Here's another approach that doesn't work:

```
protocol P: CustomStringConvertible { }

extension P where Self: RawRepresentable {
    var description: String { return "\(type(of: self)).\(self.rawValue)" }
}
```

This approach doesn't work because `E0` isn't `RawRepresentable`.  There is some magic under the hood that allows Swift to print an enum's case name even when the enum has no `rawValue`, but I'm not sure how to access it.  Using something like `Mirror(reflecting: p).description` prints the type of p, not the enum's case name.

Thank you for any ideas.  As I say it can be done in a function that receives a `P`, but a `CustomStringConvertible` would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: The issue there is the lack of a type in your enumerations. All you need to do is to define if your enumeration is a String or an Int. `enum E0: String, P { case a }`

`enum E1: Int, P { case b }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for the comment.  I do realize explicitly specifying a `RawRepresentable` type is an option, but I'd like to find a solution that doesn't impose an implementation constraint (particularly one that isn't obvious) on the protocol adopter.  If this could be a default implementation for `CustomStringConvertible` as a protocol extension in the file that declares the protocol then it is entirely self-contained.